# Terraform: What is the uri-parameter for an aws_api_gateway_integration if target is an aws_sfn_state_machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform, aws-step-functions

I want to [create a step function API using API gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html) using Terraforms [api_gateway_integration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_integration.html) and [sfn_state_machine](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/sfn_state_machine.html).

I am at the point where I have to fill the [uri-parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_integration.html#uri) at the api_gateway_integration.

My step function was created, I can reference the id of the step function (something like `arn:aws:states:*region*:*account*:stateMachine:*step-function-name*:stateMachine:*step-function-entry-point*`).

Can anyone tell me the scheme or an example of how the uri-parameter will have to look, if an AWS step function is the target?

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "endpoint_integration" {
  ...
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type = "AWS"
  uri = <<<<< What to place here???
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In contrast to [Terraform-integrate an AWS lambda with an API gateway](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_integration.html#lambda-integration), you cannot point from an API gateway to a specific AWS state machine "directly" (using the "uri"-parameter"). Instead, the aws_api_gateway_integration-resource points to the AWS state machine in general, the specific AWS state machine will be referenced by [AWS ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_gb/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) as part of the request. You can use an [API gateway request template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html) for mapping from the API gateway to the specific state machine, so that you can omit die stateMachineArn when requesting your API. For detailed explanation have a look at [AWS documentation "Creating a Step Functions API Using API Gateway"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html).

**Working example**

```
# var.aws_region = eu-central-1
# var.sfn_orchestrater_arn = arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:*account*:stateMachine:*step-function-entry-point*
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "endpoint_integration" {
  http_method             = "POST"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS"
  passthrough_behavior    = "NEVER"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.aws_region}:states:action/StartExecution"

  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<EOF
{
    "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
    "stateMachineArn": "${var.sfn_orchestrater_arn}"
}
EOF
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, above resource aws_api_gateway_integration is working fine.